# WatchService performance with many directories

Tags: java, performance, watchservice

I want to use the Java `WatchService` to listen for changes on a big number of directories (many hundreds of thousands) but I don't know if it is appropriate for such numbers of watched directories.

Does anyone have experience with `WatchService` with such numbers of directories?

If it helps, the `WatchService` will be used on CentOS 6.5 with an EXT4 file system.

Thanks,
Mickael

Comment: Just curious : what is the application of that? Why so many dirs?

Comment: The application will be used to monitor the voicemail directories created by Asterisk. Asterisk has multiple backends to store voicemails: file system, ODBC and IMAP. I'm afraid about ODBC performance so I thought I should use the file system backend.

Comment: Did you check for some asterisk api that maybe provides an event for this?

Comment: There should be something, I need to check. However, I'm still interested to know about the ability of WatchService for handling big number of watched directories.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This situation is fairly common for IDEs.  They often use directory watching for complex directory structures and many 10s of thousands of files.

There is two things to note:

- On Linux you often need to tune the OS to monitor so many files. https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/Inotify+Watches+Limit

> To prevent this situation it is recommended to increase the watches limit (to, say, 512K). You can do it by adding following line to the /etc/sysctl.conf file:

```
    fs.inotify.max_user_watches = 524288
```

This example tunes the system to monitor 512k files.

- If you have an HDD, it won't make it spin any faster and it most likely does 80 - 120 IOPS (IO Per Second) and this is more likely to be a performance bottleneck than you might like.

Like many IO  operations in Java, it is wrapper around a facility which is actually implemented by the OS.